.Net MAUI Use Preferences with Android App
I'm developing an App to run on Android and I want to use Preferences to store user settings.  The app will run fine on Windows but as soon as I run it on the Android emulator it crashes.  If I then remove the use of Preferences and use string values instead, the app run OK on the emulator.  What is the usually way of accessing the Preferences on Android? Is there some platform specific method for doing this?

please show us the relevant code

I didn't include my app as it is full of code not relevant to my questions.  However I'm using Preferences.Set(key,value) and Preferences.Get(key,"missing"). Should I be using a specific name rather than letting the third parameter default to "Default"?

OK so I built a small example and, guess what, it works so my problem is nothing directly to do with Preferences and Android.  Back to the debugging.

In short, nothing wrong except in my app.
